# Installation with nVidia

Tags: nvidia

since Ubuntu 13.04 I have been experiencing installation problems. Earlier versions used to install and work right out of the box. The symptoms are I run a live CD and boot into a desktop without access to my keyboard or mouse. I am currently trying to install Lubuntu with the same issues.

My hardware is Intel i7 quad core with nVida GTX GForce 1 gig.

I read somewhere that I have to go into compatibility mode by pressing F4 on boot. I have tried that which allowes me access to mouse & keyboard. I then install the recommended drivers. But on reboot I am back to a desktop which but no keyboard or mouse.

I am surprised no one has run into this problem already.

I look forward to a solution.

Regards
S

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install using the [alternative CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)? This uses a text based installer, and once you have installed the NVidia drivers your system should work properly.